# Replace some parts of url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to replace some parts of url using htaccess.

I am using below code but i am getting 404 error.

```
RewriteRule ^/v1/surveys/login(.*)$ /oauth2/rest/token/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is my url http://192.168.1.10/survey/api/v1/surveys/login and i want to

replace with http://192.168.1.10/survey/api/oauth2/rest/token

Comment: When in htaccess context, the path RewriteRule matches the pattern against _never starts with a slash_, that has been stripped off at that point already.

Comment: @CBroe. Thanks. Sorry i have not get your point

Comment: Make sure RewriteEngine is On. You should start from the root map, survey/api/v1/api and don't start the filename with a slash. 

So:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^survey/api/v1/surveys/login(.*)$ survey/api/oauth2/rest/token/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: First of all, where is your .htaccess file located? It would have to be in the `api` folder for this to make any sense, that the case?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/...` will never match anything in htaccess context, because the path that you are checking against this pattern _never_ starts with `/`, because that has already been removed from the path at this point.

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` located?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. My htaccess is located in root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(survey/api)/v1/surveys/login(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/oauth2/rest/token%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

# rest of the rules go below this